# using type() function to see if current string exist as table

Tags: lua

Is it possible to see if a string is the same as the name of a table?

For example:
I know that a table called 'os' exists, and I have a string `"os"`.
Is there then a way to do this:

```
x="os"
if type(x)=="table" then
    print("hurra, the string is a table")
end
```

Of course this example wont work like I want it to because

```
type(x)
```

will just return "string".

The reason why I want to do this, is just because I wanted to list all existing Lua tables, so I made this piece of code:

```
alphabetStart=97
alphabetEnd=122

function findAllTables(currString, length)

    if type(allTables)=="nil"   then
        allTables={}
    end

    if type(currString)=="table" then
        allTables[#allTables+1]=currString
    end

    if #currString < length then
        for i=alphabetStart, alphabetEnd do
            findAllTables(currString..string.char(i), length)
        end
    end
end

findAllTables("", 2)

for i in pairs(allTables) do
    print(i)
end
```

I wouldn't be surprised if there is an easier method to list all existing tables, I'm just doing this for fun in my progress of learning Lua.

Comment: This seems like a potential [xy problen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to iterate over all global variables, you can use a `for` loop to iterate over the special `_G` table which stores them:

```
for key, value in pairs(_G) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

`key` will hold the variable name. You can use `type(value)` to check if the variable is a table.

To answer your original question, you can get a global variable by name with `_G[varName]`. So `type(_G["os"])` will give `"table"`.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much. Knew there had to be an easy way to do this :)

Answer (score 4):

interjay gave the best way to actually do it. If you're interested, though, info on your original question can be found in the [lua manual](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.html). Basically, you want:

```
mystr = "os"

f = loadstring("return " .. mystr);

print(type(f()))
```

loadstring creates a function containing the code in the string. Running f() executes that function, which in this case just returns whatever was in the string mystr.